# How to export paragraph bundles with features?

Tags: 8, entities, importing-exporting, features, paragraphs

According to [paragraphs](https://www.drupal.org/project/paragraphs) documentation, it's should be possible to export paragraph bundles with [features](https://www.drupal.org/project/features) module, but whatever I search, I can't find any option in the features component section for doing this.

**Paragraphs documentation**

> **Features:** 
>   This module has some overlapping function with field_collection, but this module has some advantages over field_collection.
>
> - Different fields per paragraph bundle
> - Using different paragraph bundles in a single paragraph field
> - Displays per paragraph bundle
> - **Bundles are exportable with features.**
> - Entities, so: exportable field bases/instances, usable to show in Search API, used in Views

It seems that features not treated the same for every paragraph types because I can't see `paragraph type` in the features `component` section for some of the created paragraph types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paragraphs in D8 are entity types. So to create a feature with a paragraph bundle definition, you will need at least:

- The paragraph type definition
- The Entity form display
- The Entity view display
- The field instances you use.
- Core override fields.
- Optionally, you will need the field storage definitions.. but generally it is best to put these in a separate feature like core since fields can be used in multiple places.

The easiest way to get all these is to create a new feature and search for paragraph.[type-machine-name].  E.g. I have a paragraph type named banner, so I created a paragraph_banner feature by searching for paragraph.banner and adding the results.

Comment: Thank you so much for help and reply, But it seems that `features` not treated as same for every paragraph because I cant see `paragraph type` in the features component section for some of the created paragraph types.

Comment: Only reason I can see for this is that they may have been automatically added to another feature at some point and are being excluded.  Try checking the "Show conflicts" option to see if they show up.